# ERROR: long vectors (argument 1) are not supported in .C [in call to 'silhouette.default'] with R package NMF

Tags: r, matrix, vector, debian-based, nmf

Currently I'm running [r](/questions/tagged/r) `version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)` on a [debian](/questions/tagged/debian) server with 264 GB memory and Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU. Now I'm trying to run the [nmf](/questions/tagged/nmf) calculating for a about `(5*10^4) * 1100 matrix`, it works well when I set a specific rank, such as:

```
m1<-nmf(df.aa,rank=4,nrun=1, seed=123456,.opt='vP')
```

it returns:

```
NMF algorithm: 'brunet'
NMF seeding method: random
Iterations: 2000/2000 
DONE (stopped at 2000/2000 iterations)
```

However, when I tried to set a series of rank numbers, such as:

```
m2 <- nmf(df.aa,rank=c(2:3),nrun=1, seed=123456,.opt='vP')
```

then it threw an error:

> ````
>     Compute NMF rank= 2  ... + measures ... ERROR
>     Compute NMF rank= 3  ... + measures ... ERROR
>     Error in (function (...)  : All the runs produced an error:
>       -#1 [r=2] -> long vectors (argument 1) are not supported in .C [in call to 'silhouette.default']
>       -#2 [r=3] -> long vectors (argument 1) are not supported in .C [in call to 'silhouette.default'] ```
> ````

I'd say it quite annoyed me a little bit... I did some researches in internet but still have no idea how to fix it. Maybe the reason is that I did hit some memory limits of [nmf](/questions/tagged/nmf) package itself, or it just hit the limit of memory of the sever itself? Any info will be much appreciated.

```
    dim(df.aa)
[1] 54293  1091
```